# Generate a table subset with a list

Tags: datajoint

I have a set of subjects in a table, and I want delete a subset (e.g., subject1 and subject2). Is there a way to fetch a subset using a list? Or do I need to have an attribute I can use to select the subset?

```py
subject.Subject()

# *subject      sex    
# +----------+ +-----+
# subject1     F      
# subject2     M      
# subject3     M      
# subject4     M      

(subject.Subject & "subject=subject1").delete() # Delete individually 1
(subject.Subject & "subject=subject2").delete() # Delete individually 2

(subject.Subject & "sex='M'").delete() # Delete by attribute

(subject.Subject & "subject IN ('subject1','subject2')").delete() # pseudocode, by list

for s in ['1', '2']: # not ideal
    (subject.Subject & f'subject=\"subject{s}\"').delete(safemode=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now consider the following the most efficient:

```py
(subject.Subject & "subject in ('subject1', 'subject2')").delete()
```